# how to drop a table when using iboxdb nosql database

Tags: database, nosql

Currently, I use iboxdb database in my unity3d project with C#. Everything is fine, but i don't know how to drop table. I can not find a answer from internet and iboxdb's website. Can someone help me ? thank you !

Comment: `drop the_table_you_want`. Seriously, what have you tried so far?

Comment: if we want to insert data , we can use db.Insert("table_name", data); but there is no function db.drop.